# Raising an event when the content of an user control change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have a WPF application in which i have this user control

**View**

```
<Grid  Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=baground}" >
        <DockPanel >
            <UserControl x:Name="container"   ></UserControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

I need to add an event that is raised when the content of `container` change :

```
 private void container_LayoutUpdated_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread windowThread2 = new Thread(delegate() { verifing2(); });
            windowThread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            windowThread2.IsBackground = true;
            windowThread2.Start();

            Thread windowThread3 = new Thread(delegate() { verifing3(); });
            windowThread3.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            windowThread3.IsBackground = true;
            windowThread3.Start();
        }
```

As you can see , i tried  the event `LayoutUpdated` but it is not the best idea, i think, because it is raised many times even the `container`'s content is not changed.

- How can i resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the `container`'s content is changed directly? How the content is changed?

Comment: There is already ContentChanged event if you using ContentControl.

Comment: The `UserControl` has an event 'DataContextChanged'. Did you try with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WPF you can set to raise event for any `DependencyProperty` so if you would like to raise event on `Content` change

```
var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ContentControl.ContentProperty, typeof(UserControl));
desc.AddValueChanged(container, ContentPropertyChanged);
```

and do what you need in here:

```
private void ContentPropertyChanged(object sneder, EventArgs e)
{
   //event handler
}
```